# Display calculated value of 2 textbox values to third textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, calculation

I have calculated the two textbox values and displayed successfully it into third textbox but the issues are when I enter value to textbox1 and move to textbox2 the page get reload as I have mentioned AutoPostBack="true" for textbox1 and textbox2 and when I remove this AutoPostBack="true" the calculated value is not displayed in third textbox.

Here is my code behind

```
protected void txttotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txttotal.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdiscount.Text))
        txtgrandtotal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txttotal.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtdiscount.Text)).ToString();
}

protected void txtdiscount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txttotal.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdiscount.Text))
        txtgrandtotal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txttotal.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtdiscount.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Here is aspx code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttotal" runat="server" CssClass="textstyle" OnTextChanged="txttotal_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdiscount" runat="server" CssClass="textstyle" OnTextChanged="txtdiscount_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtgrandtotal" runat="server" CssClass="textstyle"  ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Side-Note : This is better be a client-side code (Javascript).

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload each time, remove the auto-post-back.  Then use a button to post back to the server.  Though honestly this is overkill for this operation.  JavaScript is perfectly capable of adding two numbers, you don't need all of this back-and-forth with the server for this.

Answer (score 0):

To add the two text box value and show it on third text box you can add them on button click event here is the code

**aspx page**

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
       <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Answer"></asp:Label> <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt3"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" Text="CLICK TO ADD"  OnClick="btn1_Click"/>
    </div>
```

**.cs**

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt2.Text))
        {

            txt3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txt2.Text)).ToString();
        }
    else {

        Response.Write("Please Enter Value");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @nirmala you can make a function and call it on page load event